# 6x6 sudoku puzzle, Finding what sector you're in

Tags: c++, logic, sudoku

I'm making a Sudoku solver, and I need to check if a number is free in the current sector, I already check the rows and columns of the number, so what's left is sectors.

The whole puzzle is 6x6 and has 3 (2rows per sector) row sectors and 2 (3 colums per sector) column sectors.

I check the rows and columns like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
{
    if (Matrica[i][column] == CurrentNumber) return 0;
    if (Matrica[row][i] == CurrentNumber) return 0;
}
```

and since it's a 6x6 matrix, and the sectors are 2x3(or 3x2 don't know the format)

only 2 numbers in the sector remain, and i need to find out from my row and column numbers, what places i should check, but the solution escapes me, I've no idea how to do it.

**SOLUTION:**

For anyone interested, I've worked the checking out like this:

```
int Tikrinimas(int number, int Matrica[][6], int row, int column)
{
int sectorRow = 2 * (row / 2);
int sectorCol = 3 * (column / 3);
int row1 = (row + 1) % 2;
int col1 = (column + 2) % 3;
int col2 = (column + 4) % 3;

/* Check for the value in the given row and column */
for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
{
    if (Matrica[i][column] == number) return 0;
    if (Matrica[row][i] == number) return 0;
}

/* Check the remaining two spaces in this sector */
if (Matrica[row1 + sectorRow][col1 + sectorCol] == number) return 0;
if (Matrica[row1 + sectorRow][col2 + sectorCol] == number) return 0;
return 1;
}
```

in a function this will check if current set number is viable in that position

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a grid that is divided into sectors you can find a corner of that sector and then base all or indexes of of that corner.  Assuming [0][0] is the top left corner of your puzzle then the top left corner sector you are in if you are at [3][5] would be

```
rows_per_sector (2) * (current_row (3) / rows_per_sector (2)) = 2

cols_per_sector (3) * (current_col (5) / cols_per_sector (3)) = 3
```

Now you can use 2,3 as the top left corner and you can code in the offsets need to get the rest of the sector.